# python URL parse type

Tags: python, parsing, url

How to display type of URL from the Given url as a string? 
example:
String = http://introcs.cs.princeton.edu/python

and it should display **edu**.

Comment: Do you have a specific list of websites type? edu, and what else?

Comment: What if it ends in `.co.uk`?

Comment: it should display domain type.

Comment: another example: www.google.com

Comment: `urllib.parse.urlparse('http://introcs.cs.princeton.edu/python').netloc.split('.')` gives you `['introcs', 'cs', 'princeton', 'edu']`. You can work it out from there.

Comment: output should be com

Comment: Of course, `http://216.58.193.100` would look weird.

Comment: however thanks it worked @tdelaney

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I've written this code to get the domain type

```
from urlparse import urlparse
dom = ''
parsed_uri = urlparse( 'http://introcs.cs.princeton.edu/python' )
domain = '{uri.scheme}://{uri.netloc}'.format(uri=parsed_uri)
for i in range(len(domain.split('.'))):
    dom = domain.split('.')[i]

print dom
```

P.S. This code only works for URLs starting with a protocol, like http:// or https://

You can maybe get an idea from this. Cheers!

Comment: This code worked too. Thanks!

Comment: I would have done if I had more than 15 reputations. xD

Comment: There you go. Good question though!

Comment: thanks and u got what you deserve! Thanks for the solution :)